# big theta for quad nested loop with hash table lookup

Tags: algorithm, hashtable, big-o

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++) {
                look up in a perfect constant time hash table
            }
        }
    }
}
```

what would the running time of this be in big theta?

my best guess, a shot in the dark: i always see that nested for loops are O(n^k) where k is the number of loops, so the loops would be O(n^4), then would i multiply by O(1) for constant time? what would this all be in big theta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big-theta running time would be `Θ(n^4)`.

Big-O is an upper bound, where-as big-theta is a tight bound. What this means is that to say the code is `O(n^5)` is also correct (but `Θ(n^5)` is not), whatever's inside the big-O just has to be asymptotically bigger than or equal to `n^4`.

I'm assuming `5` can be substituted for another value (i.e. is `n`), if not, the loop would run in constant time (`O(1)` and `Θ(1)`), since `5^4` is constant.

Answer (score 2):

If you consider that accessing a hash table is really theta(1), then this algorithm runs in theta(1) too, because it makes only a constant number (5^4) lookups at the hashtable.

However, if you change 5 to n, it will be theta(n^4) because you'll do exactly n^4 constant-time operations.

Answer (score 0):

Using Sigma notation:

[image]

Indeed, instructions inside the innermost loop will execute **625** times.